# web api list serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to serialize a list to xml (from a web-api method).

```
public class Result
{
  public List<string> Users { get; set; }
}
```

So I get for example:

```
<result>
  <user>Paul</user>
  <user>David</user>
  <user>Joan</user>
</result>
```

So far, I get:

```
<result>
  <users>
    <user>Paul</user>
    <user>David</user>
    <user>Joan</user>
  </users>
</result>
```

How do I tell the serialization not to wrap the user list in a "users" tag?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you just return List<User> from web api?

Comment: Thanks, yes, except in reality there is more in the Result object than just a list of User objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could either derive from `XmlObjectSerializer` and implement your own XML Serializer (see [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_media_type_formatter) FMI) or else manipulate your type so it works with the default formatter. Which isn't a great solution, but may work for a simple example, like so:

```
public class Result : List<User>
{
    //Any user added to Result will be nested directly within Result in the XML
}
```

**Further reading:**

- [MSDN: XmlObjectSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.xmlobjectserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):
  "Extend the XmlObjectSerializer to create your own serializer to serialize and deserialize objects."
- [Insights on WCF: CustomXmlObjectSerializer](https://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/customxmlobjectserializer/): Real-world example with source code.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts and links. In reality, there is more data in the Result class than just a list of User objects though, which seems to make it a little more complicated.

Comment: Yeah, I figured there would be. Hope the links help -- best of luck with your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace default DataContractSerializer with XmlSerializer in Application_Start method.

For whole project:

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

For specific type:

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.SetSerializer<Result>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result)));
```

After this you can use attributes to format your xml output:

```
public class Result
{
  [XmlElement("user")]
  public List<string> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, so I'm just curious: wouldn't that just attempt to rename the `<users>` element to `<user>`, rather than eliminating that level of the hierarchy?

Comment: It is eliminating level of hierarchy - XmlElement replaces default behavior of XmlArray.